# Can I use expect with SCP to bypass the password prompt?

Tags: bash, scp, expect

I am trying to transfer some files using SCP in a shell script, but I am being prompted for my password on the remote machine.

Can I use expect with scp to enter the password so I don't have to type it in all the time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't. Use a [key](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-keyc.html) instead.

Comment: i know but in this task i want use expect command

Comment: Using `expect` to do this is terribly insecure -- If you want an answer about using expect you are going to have to justify why you think expect is the right tool or the job.

Comment: A reason could be that he can't put his pubkey on the server or it doesn't accept publickey. Actually, scp must read the secret key too, and usually the only security on it is the 700 on the .ssh directory.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
/usr/bin/expect <<EOD
spawn /usr/bin/scp -l 200 file.ext  user@server://path/on/server/
expect "password:"
send "YourPassword\r"
expect "\r"
send "\r\n"
EOD
```

Comment: As written, this means that the user has to create/edit a shell script every time, rather than merely writing their password, which doesn't feel like a good substitute. :)

Perhaps you could improve this script by using `$@` to pass the command line parameters through to `scp`?

Answer (score 0):

You can not bypass prompt by SCP.

What you can do to enter without passphrase is to use identity file. You can do this by setting up an Identity key. Instead of using password prompt you specify the location of identity file. If you need information about how to set this up , please use the given link : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssh-key-based-authentication-on-a-linux-server